# How many ways can I force `fread` or `fwrite` to return an error code?

Tags: c, error-handling, posix, stdio

The man page for `fwrite` says:

> The function `fwrite()` returns a value less than `nitems` only if a write error has occurred.

For testing (and educating) purposes, I'd like to know what "a write error" means in this context.

The [libexplain](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/libexplain/blob/master/libexplain-1.4/libexplain/buffer/errno/fwrite.c#L53-L65) library seems to give only one possible "write error"; namely,

```
FILE *fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");  // file is not opened for writing
int rc = fwrite("foo", 1, 3, fp);
assert(rc == 0 && errno == EBADF);
```

Are there other ways to force `fwrite` to fail? If so, what are their symptoms, and how can I cause them to happen intentionally?

Same question for `fread`, also. In that case "end of file" and "file not opened for reading" are the obvious ones, but again I assume there are at least a few others.

This question applies to any kind of `FILE*`, not necessarily a disk file. Network connections, whatever weirdness you get from BSD `funopen`, and anything else that looks like a `FILE*` is fair game.

Comment: I will go out on a limb and guess that each type of `FILE`-like stream has a different set of error conditions. Which one do you really want to know about?

Comment: Try writing to `/dev/full`.

Comment: Why is "end of file" an error for `fread`? If the previous `fread` read the last byte of the file, then `0` bytes read just tells you the data has ended.

Comment: Read from a serial device at the wrong baud.  Certain to generate various read errors.

Comment: Read/write from/to a removable device while its being removed.

Comment: Flip the write-protect switch on an SD card.

Comment: An exhaustive list is **impossible**, because the errors are generated by the underlying filesystem, and new filesystems are being developed constantly. Many of the error sources are nearly impossible to deliberately cause or cause reliably. I can even think of real-world cases (with userspace filesystem access helpers) where you *think* you're reading a normal file, but due to resource starvage outside of your application, a read or write fails suddenly with an `EPIPE`. Do not try to handle *all possible errors*; just handle *all errors* you detect.

Comment: On a more positive note, for testing ones' applications against filesystem-related errors, there are [PetardFS](https://github.com/jrandall/petardfs) and [CharybdiFS](http://www.scylladb.com/2016/02/16/fault-injection-filesystem-software-testing/), FUSE filesystems that can overlay another filesystem, but inject desired errors to the operations.

Comment: Writing to a device that has no space left will generate a write error.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Well, that's the question, right? What errors *can* I detect, and what errors *are* possible? You gave a (partial?) example of `EPIPE`. Okay, what can cause `EPIPE`? (Maybe post an answer. :))

Comment: @KerrekSB: FWIW, OSX doesn't have a `/dev/full`, but trying to write to `/dev/null` gives `ENOTTY`.  On Red Hat 5.10, `/dev/full` does exist, but writing to it *succeeds*.

Comment: @Quuxplusone on this Ubuntu writing to `/dev/full` does indeed succeed, but the successive `fclose` fails with "No space left on device".

Comment: @Quuxplusone: No! You should not worry about **which** errors can occur! Your code should only check whether **an error occurred or not**. (And, if one occurred, try to describe it to the user as best you can.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Everything you just said made sense, until that parenthetical. :P How am I supposed to "describe it [the error] to the user" if I literally do not know which error has — or even *can* — occur? Isn't there *any* way to look at the state of the machine (heck, even at a coredump!) and determine *which* error has occurred? Are you honestly not understanding the question I'm asking here? because I'm running out of ways to ask it.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: The standard I/O interface does not tell you the cause of the error. It only tells you that an error occurred. So, the best you can do if `fread()` or `fwrite()` fail (so that subsequent calls to `ferror()` return nonzero), is to tell the user that a read or write error, respectively, occurred. (Other functions, like `fopen()` and `fclose()`, set `errno`, and then you can use `strerror(errno)` to describe the error to the user. POSIX I/O (`read()`, `write()`, `send()`, `recv()` etc.) do set `errno`, so their errors are easier to describe.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone No you can't have details about the error, if write fails, then just display that writing is impossible.